# Whats the reverse function of x XOR (x/2)?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, algebra

Whats the reverse function of  `x XOR (x/2)`?

Is there a system of rules for equation solving, similar to algebra, but with logic operators?

Comment: C or Python? But you might want to try something more mathematical such as maple or matlab... otherwise it'll be pretty hard

Comment: The expression is the same in both languages - it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah, i thought you want to compute the reverse of an arbitrary function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose we have a number `x` of N bits. You could write this as:

```
b(N-1) b(N-2) b(N-3) ... b(0)
```

where `b(i)` is bit number `i` in the number (where 0 is the least significant bit).

`x / 2` is the same as `x` shifted left 1 bit. Let's assume unsigned numbers. So:

```
x / 2 = 0 b(N-1) b(N-2) ... b(1)
```

Now we XOR `x` with `x / 2`:

```
x ^ (x / 2) = b(N-1)^0 b(N-2)^b(N-1) b(N-3)^b(N-2) ... b(0)^b(1)
```

Note that the rightmost bit (the most significant bit) of this is `b(N-1)^0` which is `b(N-1)`. In other words, you can get bit `b(N-1)` from the result immediately. When you have this bit, you can calculate `b(N-2)` because the second bit of the result is `b(N-2)^b(N-1)` and you already know `b(N-1)`. And so on, you can compute all bits `b(N-1)` to `b(0)` of the original number `x`.

Comment: The "^0" is true IMHO only if x is typed unsigned. With a signed type and sign extension for the division by 2 the things could look more difficult (indeterminable solution?)

Comment: I'm only interested in unsigned ints.

Comment: Does this mean there is no bitwise way of calculating this?

Comment: @jdehaan If the numbers are not unsigned then `x ^ (x / 2)` is not reversible. For example, both inputs 67 and -68 map to the same result 98. So if you get 98 you won't know if the original number was 67 or -68.

Answer (score 3):

I can give you an algorithm in bits:

Assuming you have an array of n bits:

```
b = [b1 .. bn] // b1-bn are 0 or 1
```

The original array is:

```
x0 = b0
x1 = b1 ^ x0
x2 = b2 ^ x1
```

or in general

```
x[i] = b[i] ^ x[i-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume Y = X ^ (X / 2)

If you want to find X, do this

```
X = 0

do

  X ^= Y
  Y /= 2

while Y != 0
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old topic, but I stumbled upon the same question, and I found out a little trick. If you have **n** bits, instead of requiring **n** *bits* operations (like the answer by Jesper), you can do it with **log2(n)** *number* operations :

Suppose that y is equal to x XOR (x/2) at the beginning of the program, you can do the following C program :

```
INPUT : y

int i, x;
x = y;
for (i = 1; i < n; i <<= 1)
    x ^= x >> i;

OUTPUT : x
```

and here you have the solution.

- ">>" is the right bit shift operation. For example the number 13, 1101 in binary, if shifted by 1 on the right, will become 110 in binary, thus 13 >> 1 = 6. x >> i is equivalent to x / 2^i (division in the integers, of course)
- "<<" is the left bit shift operation (i <<= 1 is equivalent to i *= 2)

Why does it work ? Let's take as example n = 5 bits, and start with y = b4 b3 b2 b1 b0 (in binary : in the following x is written in binary also, but i is written in decimal)

- Initialisation :

x = b4 b3 b2 b1 b0

- First step : i = 1

x >> 1 = b4 b3 b2 b1 so we have
x = b4 b3 b2 b1 b0 XOR b3 b2 b1 b0 = b4 (b3^b4) (b2^b3) (b1^b2) (b0^b1)

- Second step : i = 2

x >> 2 = b4 (b3^b4) (b2^b3) so we have
x = b4 (b3^b4) (b2^b3) (b1^b2) (b0^b1) XOR b4 (b3^b4) (b2^b3) = b4 (b3^b4) (b2^b3^b4) (b1^b2^b3^b4) (b0^b1^b2^b3)

- Third step : i = 4

x >> 4 = b4 so we have
x = b4 (b3^b4) (b2^b3^b4) (b1^b2^b3^b4) (b0^b1^b2^b3) XOR b4 = b4 (b3^b4) (b2^b3^b4) (b1^b2^b3^b4) (b0^b1^b2^b3^b4)

- Then i = 8, which is more than 5, we exit the loop.

And we have the desired output.

The loop has log2(n) iterations because i starts at 1 and is multiplied by 2 at each step, so for i to reach n, we have to do it log2(n) times.